# Обработка данных csv

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Имеется csv файл, в столбце которого имеются значение 1,2,3.
Знаю, что доступ к столбцу можно получить через `[]`. Но как извлечь данные этого столбца только у которого например значение 1?

```
import pandas as pd
wd = pd.read_csv(Location)
x=pd['1']
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: т.е. по сути вы уже распарсили csv и получили список списков? Тогда csv тут не причем -- работа идет уже с стандартными списками. Приведите лучше пример данных, желательный результат и код с вашей попыткой -- так намного выше шанс получить ответ

Comment: вы хотите получить строку, в которой значение в выбранном столбце равно `1`? Явно приведите минимальный пример ввода, желаемого вывода.

Comment: Да , вы меня правильно поняли. Имеется столбец и мне нужно выделить из них признаки, т.е переменной например x1 присвоить все значение у которых в данном столбце имеются в строках значения 1, и x2 у которых  значение 2 и х3  значение 3.  По  коду загрузил csv и получил доступ  к первому столбцу  x=pd['first'], а вот дальше не знаю

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы вопрос не висел не отвеченным. Насколько я понял, автор вопроса имел в виду что-то такое, судя по его комментариям:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(Location)
x1 = df.loc[df['1'] == '1'] 
x2 = df.loc[df['1'] == '2']
x3 = df.loc[df['1'] == '3']
```

Т.е. нужна выборка из `DataFrame` строк, которые удовлетворяют условию "столбец '1' равен некоему строковому числу", для этого мы вычисляем по данному столбцу битовую маску, соответствующую условию, и применяем её к `DataFrame` с помощью метода `loc`.

Answer (score -1):

Разбиваем строку на список по разделителю (запятая):

```
a = string.split(',')
```

Получаем в переменную `b` первый элемент списка `a`:

```
b = a[0]
```